# Why doesn't LiberalTypeSynonyms help in this case?

Tags: haskell, ghc

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, LiberalTypeSynonyms #-}
module Main where

data Optionally (f :: * -> *) (w :: *) = OMain w | OWrap (f w)

type MyEither1 = Either ()
type MyEither2 x = Either () x

type Works = Optionally MyEither1 Int
type Doesnt = Optionally MyEither2 Int
```

will produce the same error as if `LiberalTypeSynonyms` were not present:

```
The type synonym ‘MyEither2’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
```

From the description [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/liberal_type_synonyms.html#extension-LiberalTypeSynonyms) it seems it should first expand the type synonyms and then check validity, which should be the same for both types.

Comment: What do you think "expanding" means w.r.t. the standalone type alias `MyEither2`? What is the expansion of `MyEither2`? (Or, if you object that this is too local, I would also consider an answer to "What is the expansion of `Optionally MyEither2 Int`?" to be a good starting point for writing an answer that addresses your misunderstanding, whatever it is.)

Comment: That extension allows to pass a partially-applied type synonym to a fully applied type synonym, under certain conditions (the expansion leads to a valid type). It does not allow to pass a partially-applied type synonym to a type constructor like `Optionally`, since those can not be expanded.

Comment: @DanielWagner good insight, I didn't think hard what "expanding" means. It says "like macros" in the docs, so if I apply my c++ intuition, the expression would fail with an error like "MyEither2 does not evaluate to a term with 0 arguments", which is sort of the error we get here. Am I thinking the right way?

Comment: @MorJ Sounds about right to me!

Answer (score 1):

Haskell doesn't generally allow type synonyms to be partially applied. So in your example, `(MyEither2 Int)` can be passed as a type parameter, but `MyEither2` cannot, even if the parameter expects a kind `* -> *`.

The reasons for this are deep and hairy, and a full explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0242-unsaturated-type-families.rst), along with details of the work being done to rectify this.

`LiberalTypeSynonyms` lifts several restrictions on type synonyms, and allows passing partially-applied type synonyms to *another* type synonym. But in your example, a partially applied type synonym is being passed to a proper type, which is not (yet) possible with GHC.